# Docker on windows Vmmem grows with each rebuild of container

Tags: django, windows, docker, docker-compose

I have a Django + Gunicorn + Nginx website running in a docker container on windows 10 that's been working wonderfully.

Every time that I update my source code I run the following command to rebuild the container:

```
docker-compose up -d --build [servicename]
```

This runs as expected, builds the container detached and then swaps them out when complete, Nginx stays running and looses connection for a second then boom, back up and running.

Ill do this maybe 1-5 times a week depending on what I'm adding/fixing and pushing to production.

the issue that I just came across was that the Vmmem process is growing by a factor of 1 each time, so when I run `docker-compose up` for the first time, memory usage will be about 3,000MB. When I run my rebuild, it will grow to 6,000 MB. and on and on....

Since the system I'm running on has 32GB of RAM, I didn't notice the mass amount of buildup until a few months in of running.

Is this normal behavior from docker? and if so is there anything I can do to to alleviate the build up other than restarting the computer?

-restarting docker does not solve the issue
-pruning does not solve the issue

Edit:
Here is the docker-compose.yml I'm currently using;

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./static:/static
      - ./media:/media

  site:
    restart: always
    build: ./
    container_name: site
    command: bash -c "python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn --workers=8 --worker-class gevent --timeout 120 Site.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/src
      - ./static:/static
      - ./media:/media
    expose:
      - "8080" 
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

I have also limited the wsl2 memory consumption to 8GB with

```
%UserProfile%\.wslconfig

[wsl2]
memory=8GB
```

This seems to be working with limiting the consumption to the host machine, but Vmmem still grows up to a max of 8,000MB after each rebuild. I've heard that Linux likes to hold onto its RAM and dump it only when needed, so could that be what I'm seeing here?

Comment: That doesn't sound normal; do you have a [mcve] demonstrating this setup?  (Does your `docker-compose.yml` file have both `build:` and `image:` lines; what is the Dockerfile `FROM` line?)  Have you done any research to see where the memory is actually going?

Comment: @DavidMaze unfortunately I don't have a MRE that I can generate at the moment, I'll look into putting one together (thanks for the link). But I've edited the question with some more information like the `docker-compose.yml` which shows the `build:` line that builds from source. I've come up short on research as no one seems to be experiencing the same issue. What I have found was to limit the WSL memory limit as described in the edit of my post and that Linux likes to hold onto unused memory instead of dumping it, which I'm a little unsure of. Thanks for your reply and help!